# How to execute a PKG file using a custom universal keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, macos, dmg

It may sound strange but I need to run a specific PKG installer whenever I trigger a specific custom keyboard shortcut. On Sierra 12.6 I've assigned a custom keyboard shortcut to sleep/lock-screen the Mac using shellScript/appleScript.

I have no idea how the shell script would look like.

I'd be grateful for any help and participation.

Comment: DMG files are disk image files, they are a type of container, not executables, nor are they installers per-se! They can contain an installer, but installers are typically package files, that have the .pkg extension.

Comment: @user3439894 You're completely right. It was my fault. The installer is a .pkg file.

Comment: You can use something like: `do shell script "open /path/to/filename.pkg"` That said, your question lacks enough specific information for me to post a full and or complete answer. Also Finder and probably System Events can use their `open` _command_ to start the .pkg file as well. So there is more than one way to go.

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you. I've saved it as a service. It works within Automator but the assigned keyboard shortcut cannot execute and launch the .pkg file. Is there any trick to know why it's not working?

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks! I got it to work! There was sth wrong with the name, I think.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Here is an example using Finder and the filename.pkg file, say stored in your Downloads folder. You can use the following with changing just `filename.pkg` to the actual `.pkg` filename: `tell application "Finder" to open alias ((path to downloads folder) & "filename.pkg" as string)`

Comment: I can accept this might not apply necessarily to whatever it is you're doing, but in general, you needn't use a script to assign a keyboard shortcut to trigger screen sleep or lock.  The  menu has both `"Sleep"` and `"Lock Screen"` items, meaning you can set a shortcut via _System Preferences_. I'm coming from High Sierra, but I believe I recall the same capability in Sierra, if perhaps in a slightly different part of _System Preferences_.